# How to make sure I don't oversell tickets with Laravel and Stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a Laravel 9 app, where admins can create events and a limited number of tickets, with different conditions (this means an event can have multiple types of tickets, with different conditions and different prices), then, users can buy those tickets.
I want to make sure each user can buy only one ticket for each event, and assure that if payment is made, this user will receive their ticket.

My concerns are that I need to make sure that each ticket is reserved to one user and one user only at a time. After that, I want to make sure every time user has completed payment, that his reserved ticket is marked as sold, no matter what.

I know I should be using some sort of webhook as a callback, but I couldn't figure out what events should i listen to, or how to set up properly those webhooks in my Laravel App.

If anyone knows any way to do it better, I am completely open to a redesign.

I currently have this setup, where each type of ticket belongs to one event. Then, when admin publishes that ticket for n people, n unique sellable tickets (usts) are created (this is each and every one of the individual tickets people can buy, with a unique identifier).

When a user wants to buy one ticket, I have a controller that first reserves that ticket for that user.

1. Check out if is there any unique sellable ticket (ust) that is currently not sold or reserved to anyone.
2. If there is any avaiable ust, create Stripe Checkout Session and store Stripe Session Id to that ust object in database.
3. After payment is completed, the return url calls another method that does the next:
   3.1. Find any unique sellable tickets reserved to user, but not yet marked as sold.
   3.2. Foreach ticket that logged in user has reserved but not sold, check out in Stripe api if payment has been completed.
   3.3 If payment has been completed, check sold as true.

Notes: I have set up stripe Checkout to expire in 30 minutes, so thats why i select any usthat is marked as not sold and reserved more than 30 minutes ago as available.

These are my reserving ticket and Stripe Callback functions so far:

```
    public function ReserveEventTicket($event, $ticket){
        try {
            $event = Event::where('slug', $event)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withErrors(['Evento no encontrado']);
        }

        if(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->end_datetime)->isPast()){
            return back()->withErrors(['Este evento ya ha terminado.']);

        }

        try {
            $ticket = Ticket::where('slug', $ticket)->where('event_id', $event->id)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withErrors(['Entrada no encontrada']);
        }

        //El usuario no ha comprado la entrada.
        foreach ($event->tickets as $us_ticket) {
            $AlreadyBoughtFound = $us_ticket->usts->where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
            if($AlreadyBoughtFound->count() != 0){
                return back()->withErrors(['¡No tan rápido! No puedes comprar otra entrada para este evento.']);
            }
        }    
        

        //Reservar ticket
        try {
            $UST = Ust::where('ticket_id', $ticket->id)
            ->where(function($q){
                $q->where('reserved_datetime', '<', Carbon::parse()->subMinutes(32));
                $q->orWhere('reserved_datetime', null);
            })
            ->where('sold', false)->lockForUpdate()->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withErrors(['No quedan entradas disponibles.']);
        }
       
        try {
            DB::transaction(function () use($UST) {
                 $reserveUST = $UST->update([
                    'reserved' => true,
                    'reserved_to' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'reserved_datetime' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ]);
            
                
                if(\Session::has('referral')){
                    
                    $pr = PrVenue::where('code', \Session::get('referral'))->get()->first();
                    if($pr){
                        if($pr->venue_id == $UST->ticket->event->venue->id){
                            $addReferralSold = ReferralTransaction::create([
                                'ticket_id' => $UST->id,
                                'user_id' => $pr->user_id,
                                'distributor' => $pr->distributor,
                            ]);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
         } catch (\Throwable $th) {
             return back()->withErrors(['Error reservando la entrada'.$th]);
         }

        try {
            if($ticket->pay_at_door){
                    if(config('pricing.payments.pay_at_door.style') == "variable"){
                    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(config('services.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
                    $price = $stripe->prices->retrieve($ticket->stripe_price_id,[]);
                    $application_fee = round(config('pricing.pamyments.pay_at_door.amount')*$price->unit_amount*100, 0);
                }else if(config('pricing.payments.pay_at_door.style') == "fixed"){
                    $application_fee = config('pricing.pamyments.pay_at_door.amount');
                }
            }else{
                $application_fee = 140;
            }

            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.STRIPE_API_KEY'));
            $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'line_items' => [[
                'price' => $ticket->stripe_price_id,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => "https://phplaravel-843314-2906175.cloudwaysapps.com/events/SucessCallback?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            'cancel_url' => url('events/SucessCallback?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'),
            'client_reference_id' => $UST->id,
            'expires_at' => time() + (60 * 30), 
            'payment_intent_data' => [
                'application_fee_amount' => $application_fee,
                'transfer_data' => [
                'destination' => $event->organization->stripe_user_id
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        DB::transaction(function () use($session, $UST) {
            $associateUST = $UST->update([
                'stripe_session_id' => $session->id
            ]);
        });

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withErrors(['Error en la pasarela de pago. Volver a intentar.'.$th]);
        }
        return redirect($session->url);
    }

    public function SuccessfullPaymentCallback(Request $req){
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(config('services.STRIPE_API_KEY'));
         $session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
            $req->session_id,[]);

        //Check if session has been completed and if user matches.
        if($session->payment_status == 'paid'){
            try {
                DB::transaction(function () use($session) {
                    $UST = Ust::where('reserved', true)->where('stripe_session_id', $session->id)->where('id', $session->client_reference_id)->firstOrFail();
                    $update = $UST->update([
                        'receiver_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                        'sold' => true
                    ]);
                    
                    $NewUST = $UST->refresh();

                    $updateReferralSold = ReferralTransaction::where('ticket_id', $UST->id)->update([
                        'sold' => true,
                    ]);
                });
                $ust = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->usts->where('stripe_session_id', $session->id)->first();  
                $tick = array();
                $tick['code'] = $ust->code; 
                $tick['event_name'] = $ust->ticket->event->name; 
                $tick['event_link'] = url('events/'.$ust->ticket->event->slug); 
                $tick['event_image'] = ImageController::ShowImage($ust->ticket->event->poster); 
                $tick['venue_name'] = $ust->ticket->event->venue->name; 
                $tick['zone'] = $ust->ticket->zone->name ?? '-'; 
                $tick['ticket'] = $ust->ticket->name; 
                $tick['limit_time'] = ($ust->ticket->time_limit) ? $ust->ticket->max_datetime : '-'; 
                //Revisar esto bien
                Storage::put('public/ust_'.$tick['code'].'.png', \QrCode::format('png')->merge('/public/images/icons/icon-128x128bg.png')->size(400)->generate($tick['code']));

                Mail::send('mails.TicketEmail', ["tick"=>$tick], function($message)use($tick) {
                    $message->to(Auth::user()->email, Auth::user()->email)
                            ->subject('Entrada para '.$tick['event_name']);
                });
                //Mail::to([])->send(new TicketEmail($ust->ticket->id, $ust->code, $ust->stripe_session_id));

            } catch(\Throwable $th) {
                Storage::put('file.txt', $th);
                Storage::put('file.png', \QrCode::format('png')->merge('/public/images/icons/icon-128x128bg.png')->size(400)->generate('dsalfjadshñfjah'));

                return back()->withErrors(['No se ha completado el proceso de adquisición de tu entrada. Vuelve a iniciar sesión para arreglar el problema.']);
            }
        
        }else{
            try {
                $UST = Ust::where('reserved', true)->where('stripe_session_id', $session->id)->where('id', $session->client_reference_id)->update([
                    'reserved' => false,
                    'stripe_session_id' => null,
                    'reserved_to' => null,
                    'reserved_datetime' => null,
                    'receiver_id' => null
                ]);
            } catch(\Throwable $th) {
                return back()->withErrors(['El pago no se ha completado y no se ha adquirido tu entrada.']);
            }
        }
        return redirect(url('me/wallet'))->with('success', 'Compra completada correctamente.');
        

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> After payment is completed, the return url calls another method that does the next: 3.1. Find any unique sellable tickets reserved to user, but not yet marked as sold. 3.2. Foreach ticket that logged in user has reserved but not sold, check out in Stripe api if payment has been completed. 3.3 If payment has been completed, check sold as true.

If you implement webhook events, you won't have to loop over each ticket in your system. Instead, you'll automatically get a `checkout.session.completed` webhook event from Stripe that will inform you of which ticket has been purchased. So in your webhook handler code, you can mark the ticket as "sold".

I'm not a Laravel expert but here are a few resources on how you can handle webhooks [0] [1]. The concept is basically that Stripe sends you a POST request with an Event object in the request body. You set up an endpoint where Stripe sends that request and you return an HTTP response to it.

[0] https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks

[1] https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/stripe-webhooks-with-laravel

Comment: Thank you very much, I would still appreciate some help with Laravel Transaction methods, that locks database...